# How can I check if RESTAPI is down using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I wants to make a virtual environment to check if web-service is down.

Case: If web-service is down for 7 seconds then system should re-try once and if not work then it should send the notification to admin.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
// Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 7);
// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$responseData = curl_exec($ch); 

$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$url = 'my.url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($retcode == 200)
{
    // It's working
}
else
{
    // It's down
}
```

Comment: Hello, Please revise my question once more and help me to get ride of the problem.

Comment: This above code checks for an url, and returns its HTTP return code. If it's 200, then it's up, otherwise you may have problems. If you currently have troubles, please add them in your first post. Right now, we don't know what are the problems in your code.

Comment: Actually my code is working fine but i received a client requirement that if system is hitting a web-service and its down then system should check that for 7 seconds and if it not get response then program should sleep for 5 seconds and try again. The problem is i can't tell web-services provider to make services down to test my code. So do you have any idea how can i make virtual environment for it.

Comment: You can simply try to query a non existing url, which will makes you retry 7 seconds after, and then send you a mail

Comment: Yes, i already did that but program is getting response before 7 seconds and due to that i am unable to test the case.

Comment: What do you mean getting response before 7 seconds?

Comment: If I am trying the code with none-existing URL then its getting response before 7 seconds rather than to search it for 7 seconds.

Comment: I mentioned my code under my question. Please check it once.

Comment: I found the solution for this. We can just put the url like http://google.co.in:8080/

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.

```
function checkData($loop = 0){
    $url = 'http://google.co.in:8080/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    // Use 0 to wait indefinitely.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 7);
    // The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $responseData = curl_exec($ch); 

    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curl_errno > 0){
        if($loop > 1 ){
           //send mail to admin
        }else{
           $loop++;
           sleep(7);
           checkData();
        }
    }
}
checkData();
```

Comment: This is NOT the answer to your client requirement, please check the requirement well. Where is your **sleep for 5 seconds** code?

Comment: Why you asking for sleeping time because its not required. I was trying to make the environment if server is not responding but now all working fine and approved by our Programming Manager, Testers and Clients.

Comment: well its what you said in your comment, "and if it not get response then program should **sleep** for 5 seconds and try again"

Comment: @DineshChand : I just posted the basic solution and i believe a good developer can modify that. Now i edited by answer.